# How Class Lookup happens in Android ART?

Tags: art

As per my understanding of AOT( Ahead of Time ) compilation in ART, dex files are converted into native codes at the time of installation. Does that mean that the dex files are never referred after the installation? If this is so, then why there is the entry for dex file references in OAT files.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google IO video on ART the speaker states that the DEX files are kept around for class loading and debugging. https://youtu.be/EBlTzQsUoOw?t=9m20s

Comment: so how does the class loading happens using these dex files, do you have any idea?